# How to display data from a database file onto pyqt so that the user can add/delete/edit the data?

Tags: python, sql, qt, pyqt

I have made a database file using SQL commands in python. i have used quite a lot of foreign keys as well but i am not sure how to display this data onto qt with python? any ideas? i would also like the user to be able to add/edit/delete data

Comment: you need to show us some code in order to help you, at least the basic form with all the related widgets and the grid...or simply read https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578676-a-phone-book-gui-built-in-wxpython-connected-to-da/?in=user-4187866 one of my recipes on ActiveState but i used there wxpython

Comment: I have not done that yet..i am not sure how to, i don't know what to do in order to display any information from a database file - and i am using pythonQt

Comment: ok @Thaz... start by designing your gui with qtdesigner it is a drag and drop IDE. if you are on windows search in the file browser for it. i have also edited my first comment please check it.

Comment: alright, is there anything specific that i would need to drag and drop onto the widget? yep, i have read it thanks.

Comment: you first open qtdesigner and you have a form, on this form add labels, textboxes, and buttons and a grid upon what you need.. i advise you to follow the zetcode tutorial http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/ there you will have a feel of what that might be

Comment: yeah i know how to do that, i have made a couple of forms with it already. its just the fact that i dont know how to import data from a database file to be displayed to the user on qt

Answer (score 3):

since the question is a bit broad and general please start by http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/ it will help you a lot to get started. Once you know what you are dealing with you can make your user forms with the QtDesigner and add functions to your events there but be careful each time you edit the form in Qt all your added python code will be deleted so i advise that you follow an MVC pattern for your project.

EDIT: this might be an abstract of what you need to display data : considet qttable is your grid in your class

```
def fillQTable(self):
    #data = [('1','2','3','4'),('5','6','7','8')] #this is from database
    data = self.getData()
    rowCount = len(data)
    colCount = 4
    self.qttable.setRowCount(rowCount)
    self.qttable.setColumnCount(colCount)
    self.qttabke.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.qttabke.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("num1;num2;num3;num4").split(";"))
    self.qttabke.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
    for s in range(colCount):
        self.qttable.horizontalHeaderItem(s).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(col)
            self.qttabke.setItem(i, j, item)

def connectionDB(self):
    try:
        cnn=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}\
                           ;DBQ=Data.mdb") # you can use the db library you like here
                                           # i have used pyodbc to connect to MS  Access db
        return cnn
    except Exception, e:
        print e

def getData(self):
    cnn = self.connectionDB()
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from DataTable") # DataTable is a table in Data.mdb
    rawData = cursor.fetchall()
    cnn.commit()
    cnn.close()
    return rawData
```

Comment: yeah i know how to do that, i have made a couple of forms with it already. its just the fact that i dont know how to import data from a database file to be displayed to the user on qt

Comment: yes, i think it may be a bit helpful, but how do i connect the database to the python file, so that i do not have to manually put the data into the list

Comment: you need to create a function that connects to your database file and returns the list that i referred to as "data" in the code i'll just add it now

Comment: @Thaz i guess that you have a full answer now if this was useful for you please press on the correct sign to vote. please let me know if this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit broad, but I'll try answering it anyway. Qt does come with some models that can be connected to a database. Specifically classes like `QSqlTableModel`. If you connect such a model to your database and set it as the model for a `QTableView` it should give you most of the behavior you want.

Unfortunately I don't think I can be any more specific than that. Once you have written some code, feel free to ask a new question about a specific issue (remember to include example code!)